# Can Spring Boot use as command line app and as server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to use a Spring Boot app as a command-line application with command-line switches, as well as a server? I would like users to be able to invoke the app with command arguments, execute the desired action, and then exit.

However, I would also like the app to have the ability to start as a server and listen for REST requests. For example, for the command-line usage:

```
'./myapp -n:1 -b:2',
```

And for the server mode:

```
 './myapp -a:server'`,
```

it would start the app as a server.

Comment: Sure you can. Based on your parameter enable/disable the web parts of your application that way Spring Boot will not start the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got options, you can use the `SpringApplicationBuilder` and based on the property you can set the `web` parameter to NONE/SERVLET or you could modify the incoming arguments to add a parameter so Spring Boot knows what to do. Either way should work.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

  var server = ObjectUtils.containsElement(args, "-a:server");
  var type = server ? WebApplicationType.SERVLET : WebApplicationType.NONE;
  var application = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
     .sources(Bar.class)
     .web(type).build();
  application.run(args);
}
```

Or you could modify the incoming arguments and add `spring.main.web-application-type` with the value based on what you pass in.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

  var server = ObjectUtils.containsElement(args, "-a:server");
  var param = "spring.main.web-application-type=" + ( server ? "SERVLET" : "NONE");
  var argsToUse = ObjectUtils.addObjectToArray(args, param);
  SpringApplication.run(Bar.class, argsToUse);
}
```

Comment: what is this void(....) method ?

Comment: For some reason I decided to leave out the `main`. Fixed.

Comment: what is the Bar.class , why i need it ?

Comment: That is your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, I do assume some basic java and SPring Boot knowledge if you ask questions like you did.

Comment: you mean like in simple spring app you do : SpringApplication(Foo.class)

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. There was a discussion for basically this topic [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20404), but basically you can define a program argument and then create a simple `if...else` in `main` method for your needs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if ("n1".equals(args[0])) {
        // foo
    } else {
        SpringApplication.run(Bar.class, args);
    }
}
```